# Define specific route to nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api

I've been trying rails and I found myself with a very simple problem: I have two models, survivors and locations, and they're nested resources in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :survivors do
        resources :locations
      end
      resources :abduction_reports
    end
  end
end
```

which gives me almost all the routes I need. The problem is that survivors and locations is one-to-one association, so if I want to update the survivor location, it seems more interesting if the end-point for that is

```
PUT /survivors/:survivor_id/location
```

To solve it, I did this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
        [...]
        put 'survivors/:survivor_id/location', to: 'locations#update'
    end
  end
end
```

but it doesn't seem the correct way to do it... I mean, can it be defined inside the 'resources :survivors do ... end' scope?

I probably have already seen it in the rails documentation, but I think I just haven't realized how to adapt the documentation examples to my problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a singular resource use the `resource` macro instead:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :survivors do
        resource :location
      end
      resources :abduction_reports
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
                       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                            Controller#Action
     api_v1_survivor_location POST   /api/v1/survivors/:survivor_id/location(.:format)      api/v1/locations#create
 new_api_v1_survivor_location GET    /api/v1/survivors/:survivor_id/location/new(.:format)  api/v1/locations#new
edit_api_v1_survivor_location GET    /api/v1/survivors/:survivor_id/location/edit(.:format) api/v1/locations#edit
                              GET    /api/v1/survivors/:survivor_id/location(.:format)      api/v1/locations#show
                              PATCH  /api/v1/survivors/:survivor_id/location(.:format)      api/v1/locations#update
                              PUT    /api/v1/survivors/:survivor_id/location(.:format)      api/v1/locations#update
                              DELETE /api/v1/survivors/:survivor_id/location(.:format)      api/v1/locations#destroy
             api_v1_survivors GET    /api/v1/survivors(.:format)                            api/v1/survivors#index
                              POST   /api/v1/survivors(.:format)                            api/v1/survivors#create
          new_api_v1_survivor GET    /api/v1/survivors/new(.:format)                        api/v1/survivors#new
         edit_api_v1_survivor GET    /api/v1/survivors/:id/edit(.:format)                   api/v1/survivors#edit
              api_v1_survivor GET    /api/v1/survivors/:id(.:format)                        api/v1/survivors#show
                              PATCH  /api/v1/survivors/:id(.:format)                        api/v1/survivors#update
                              PUT    /api/v1/survivors/:id(.:format)                        api/v1/survivors#update
                              DELETE /api/v1/survivors/:id(.:format)                        api/v1/survivors#destroy
```

See:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources